# Умный поиск в django

Tags: база-данных, django, sqlite, поиск, выборка

Допустим, в базе данных `Person` имеются такие записи

```
+----+-------------------+
| id |        fio        | 
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Петров Алексей    | 
|  2 | Андреев Валентин  | 
+----+-------------------+
```

Тогда, с помощью обычного фильтра `Person.filter(fio__contains='Петров')` мы получим первую запись. Но если вместо строки Петров вбить Алексей Петров, то он уже нам выдаст нулевой результат. То же касается и с сокращениями, например если вбить Петров А. Что же делать в данной ситуации.

Comment: Разбить фио на три колонки и искать по каждому отдельно?

Comment: Или же организовывать полнотекстовый поиск, смотря насколько умный поиск нужен

Comment: @andreymal, сам поиск организован в ember. При делении каждой колонки еще на три, не повлияет ли это на производительность? Можно поподробнее насчет полнотекстового поиска?

Comment: Производительность играет ключевую роль, записей может быть очень много

Comment: По полнотекстовому поиску это гуглить в сторону Sphinx/Solr/ElasticSearch, у меня Sphinx на 10 миллионах записей неплохо работает

Comment: Нужно лишь учитывать, что пользователь может поменять местами слова и может сократить

Comment: поверьте, производительность здесь не играет никакой роли вообще - разницу даже в десять миллисекунд, которой никогда не будет, пользователи не заметят

Comment: Странно, вообще contains ищет по всему полю, а не только в начале. Проблема действительно воспроизвелась?

Comment: @Mae, вы правы, contains ищет по всему полю. Но что если пользователь наберет слова в разброс. Например не Петров Алексей, а Алексей Петров, тогда contains не найдет. Ниже способ работает

Comment: У меня другая СУБД, возможно, это особенность SQLite, но у меня сейчас нашёл и Петров Алексей, и аПетров, и Алексей Петров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стал много мудрить, сделал простым способом:

```
search_str = search_str.replace('.', ' ')
search_str_split = search_str.split(' ')
for item in search_str_split:
    query = Person.filter(fio__contains=item)
```

Мне нужно было при создании пользователя вывести сообщение, что пользователь с таким ФИО возможно уже существует. Если пользователь наберет `Петров А.`, то я просто убираю точку, делю строку на слова и проверяю каждое слово. Если пользователь введет ФИО задом на перед, то данный метод тоже работает. Не знаю правильно ли, но как говорил мой дед "Работает, не трогай".